# Hide "loader" div when first image in stack loads?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a div that covers the page content until the first image in a set for a slideshow loads.  The code I'm using to hide this div is as follows, but it's not working:

```
$(function() {
  $('.slide').first(function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
      $('#loader').fadeOut('slow');
    });
  });
});
```

Any idea why?  The "loader" div doesn't hide even after the entire page loads.  I have had some success running $('#loader').fadeOut('slow'); on (window).load().

Comment: Can we see the HTML of your loaded images?

Comment: They're loaded via another jQuery function via JSON, so they don't show up in the source... You can see them in the Chrome Inspector (or equivalent) here, though: http://new.element17.com

Comment: You should get the src to the first image from the json, create a new JS image object, and attach the fadeout to the onload function of the image object.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would be done?  Sorry, I'm very inexperienced with JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are being loaded via ajax and are not present when the DOM first loads. Try hiding the loading image after the first image is added to the DOM.

```
$.each(images, function(index) {
  $('#slideshow').append('<div class="slide" style="background-image:url(' + this + ');"></div>');
  if(index === 0){
    $('#loader').fadeOut('slow');
  }
});
```

Comment: ah, you're loading the .slide divs dynamically...these elements don't exist on the page when JQuery is testing for load

Comment: Right... The code that is loading the divs is as follows: `$.getJSON('../functions.php', function(images) {$.each(images, function() {$('#slideshow').append('<div class="slide" style="background-image:url(' + this + ');"></div>');});$('#slideshow').cycle();});`  Is there any way to get it to hide #loader after the first load of .each()?

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to hide the loader div right away, before the first image is finished loading.